# jQuery Mobile and scale

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm toying with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile, I find that the default styles look rather small on my testing device (HTC nexus one), I'm frankly new to mobile web development (heck, smart phones in general...), so I'm not entirely sure if this is typical or not, but everything is just too small/rather hard to read and fill up.

I've tried something like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=3, maximum-scale=4">
```

(increased scale and all), but so far had no success.

How should I go about scaling up my app?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile capable of scaling your mobile app. If  you start to scale up your mobile for your Nexus One then things will go ugly on larger screens. Buttons and other UI elements will look bigger.

Why don’t you visit some [jQuery Mobile sites](http://www.jqmgallery.com/) and see how it looks on your Nexus One. If they also look small, leave things the way it is. Don’t mess it up and spoil the usability for rest of your users who use devices other than Nexus S.

Comment: Thank you for your input, if you could please take a look at my answer and see if this is a reasonable global fix for my issues, I would be grateful. And yes, compared to those example sites, my app was far too small.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to "fix" this, I set the `target-densitydpi` in viewport to `medium-dpi`, so in final: `target-densitydpi=medium-dpi`, on this phone, everything looks proper sized.

I do not know how this affects other phones though.

Comment: you better check it on high density device and see how it looks.